# NLP/Regex: capture one sequence of each repeated word pattern in a text

Tags: regex, awk, sed, pattern-matching, nlp

EX: in the following text I have

---

craters in the sand that you left outdoors differ in appearance from the craters in the sand that you left outdoors differ in appearance from the craters in the sand that you left outdoors differ in appearance from the ...

Moon and other bodies in space helped scientists understand how gravity works. ...

How space exploration has helped us to learn more about Earth How space exploration has helped us to learn more about Earth How space exploration has helped us to learn more about Earth How space exploration has helped us to learn more about Earth How space exploration has helped us to learn more about Earth ...

---

And I only want to capture once of each repeated word pattern:

craters in the sand that you left outdoors differ in appearance from the Moon and other bodies in space helped scientists understand how gravity works. How space exploration has helped us to learn more about Earth

---

NB: Text is all in one line so look something more like

craters in the sand that you left outdoors differ in appearance from the craters in the sand that you left outdoors differ in appearance from the craters in the sand that you left outdoors differ in appearance from the Moon and other bodies in space helped scientists understand how gravity works. How space exploration has helped us to learn more about Earth How space exploration has helped us to learn more about Earth How space exploration has helped us to learn more about Earth How space exploration has helped us to learn more about Earth How space exploration has helped us to learn more about Earth ...

Comment: do you mean the longest repeating sequence? because there are too many repeating sequences.

Comment: By example. In this text I need to capture: 
On time:
`craters in the sand that you left outdoors differ in appearance from the`

One time:
`Moon and other bodies in space helped scientists understand how gravity works`
and One time:
`How space exploration has helped us to learn more about Earth`

Comment: If I'm understanding you, you want to capture repeating text, but there are no limitations on (a) what the length or content of those repeating snippets contains and (b) because it's a single line, there's no "boundaries" at which each element should be searched. This is quite a task.

Comment: Exactly. I am trying to split the problem in smaller subset task. 
I Tried a Natural Language Processing tool  to extract sentences. But trained algorithm could not do the task. OpenNLP(Sentence Detector)

Comment: So, if the text is `the the`, `the` is the first repeat. What if it's `the the and the the and`. What's the repeat? `the` (because that single word is repeated)? Or `the the and`? This is a project that requires some real limitations in order to avoid infinite possibilities. I definitely do not see regex as a solution here. Part of the solution perhaps.

Comment: I get your point. In my current case it would be `the the and` but in implementation `the` is causing an issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your sample, the repeated phrase always follows immediately after the original; can we count on that?  Also, are you free to use a regex flavor/tool/language other than awk or sed?  If the answer to both questions is yes, a pure regex solution might be possible.  This should work in most of the Perl-derived flavors (PHP, .NET, Perl, etc):

```
\b(\w+(?:\W+\w+)+?)\W+(?=\1\b)
```

I'm making a passel of simplifying assumptions here so I can concentrate on the technique.  A word is defined as a group of word characters, delimited from neighboring words by one or more non-word characters (e.g. whitespace and punctuation).

The first part - `\b(\w+(?:\W+\w+)+?)` - matches a "phrase" at least two words long, capturing it in group #1.  The second part - `\W+(?=\1\b)` - tries to match the same phrase again, but doesn't consume it.  If the match succeeds, we replace it with an empty string, effectively deleting the first phrase along with the `\W+` that introduces the second phrase, but not the second phrase itself.

Be aware that the second phrase has to be *exactly* the same the first one, including capitalization and the number and kinds of whitespace characters between the words.  In other words, this is a very brittle solution.  I strongly recommend you keep working on the NLP approach.  Regexes force you to deal with syntax all the time, when you should be working at the semantic level.  (This is one of the main reasons why we urge people not to use regexes on HTML.)

Comment: the following work fine for the first line. But not for the rest of the string. I tried by adding "g" at the end of the pattern match but output was not right. Any Idea?

Comment: My perl test

`$mystring = "craters in the sand that you left outdoors differ in appearance from the craters in the sand that you left outdoors differ in appearance from the Moon and other bodies in space helped scientists understand how gravity works. How space exploration has helped us to learn more about Earth How space exploration has helped us to learn more about Earth How space exploration has helped us to learn more about";

my @sentences = $mystring =~ /\b(\w+(?:\W+\w+)+?)\W+(?=\1\b)/;

print "@sentences\n";`

Comment: Yes, the `g` flag is necessary, but you should be doing a global *substitution*, not a global match: `$mystring =~ s/\b(\w+(?:\W+\w+)+?)\W+(?=\1\b)//g;`

Comment: Following implementation worked perfectly for my current case. I agree tough that on a long run I will need to go deeper in an NLP solution and take in account the semantic structure of the sentence.

Comment: `$mystring = "craters in the sand that you left outdoors differ in appearance from the craters in the sand that you left outdoors differ in appearance from the craters in the sand that you left outdoors differ in appearance from the Moon and other bodies in space helped scientists understand how gravity works. How space exploration has helped us to learn more about Earth How space exploration has helped us to learn more about Earth"; $mystring =~ s/\b(\w+(?:\W+\w+)+?)\W+(?=\1\b)//g; print "$mystring\n";`

Answer (score 0):

Bruteforce:

```
s = 'craters in the sand that you left outdoors differ in appearance from the craters in the sand that you left outdoors differ in appearance from the craters in the sand that you left outdoors differ in appearance from the Moon and other bodies in space helped scientists understand how gravity works. How space exploration has helped us to learn more about Earth How space exploration has helped us to learn more about Earth How space exploration has helped us to learn more about Earth How space exploration has helped us to learn more about Earth How space exploration has helped us to learn more about Earth'

ss = [s[i:] for i in xrange(len(s))]
ss = sorted(ss)

all_matches = []
for i in xrange(len(ss)-1):
    a = ss[i]
    b = ss[i+1]
    cap = min(len(a), len(b))
    for j in xrange(cap):
        if a[j] <> b[j]:
            if j > 0:
                all_matches.append(a[:j])
            break
        elif j+1 == cap:
            all_matches.append(a[:j+1])

def match_exist(matches, m):
    for m2 in matches:
        if m in m2:
            return True
    return False

matches = []
all_matches.sort(key=len, reverse=True)
for m in all_matches:
    if not match_exist(matches, m):
        matches.append(m)

for m in matches:
    print m
```

outputs:

```
 How space exploration has helped us to learn more about Earth How space exploration has helped us to learn more about Earth How space exploration has helped us to learn more about Earth How space exploration has helped us to learn more about Earth
craters in the sand that you left outdoors differ in appearance from the craters in the sand that you left outdoors differ in appearance from the 
ie
st
```

If you don't want overlapping matches, then you can just use regex backreference:

```
(\b.+\b)\1
```

[demo](http://regex101.com/r/nI4aE7/1)

Comment: I just re-edited my question to clarify that I need one occurrence of each repeated patter sequence:

ex: 
In this text I need to capture: On time: `craters in the sand that you left outdoors differ in appearance from the` One time: `Moon and other bodies in space helped scientists understand how gravity works` and One time: `How space exploration has helped us to learn more about Earth`

Comment: @user3641949, in that case, it's much easier, see updated answer